# Creating my own mapper

Tags: c#, generics, mapping, ienumerable

so here is my situation. I have 2 classes, TmdbTvShow and TvShow.

TmdbTvShow is a class filled with data i've got from a external source. now I want to create a some kind of mapper to map it to my own class, TvShow.

Class TvShow:

```
 [MovieMap("TmdbTvShow")]
public class TvShow
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MovieMapProperty("ID")]
    public int TmdbID { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("OriginalName")]
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("Overview")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("FirstAirDate")]
    public DateTime FirstAirDate { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("LastAirDate")]
    public DateTime LastAirDate { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("Genres")]
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    [MovieMapProperty("InProduction")]
    public bool Running { get; set; }

}
```

Mapper class:

```
public class MovieMapper
{
    public MovieMapper()
    {          
    }

    public T Map<T>(object input) where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();

        MovieMapAttribute[] classAttributes = (MovieMapAttribute[])obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MovieMapAttribute), false);

        if (classAttributes != null && classAttributes[0].ClassName.Equals(input.GetType().Name))
        {
            Dictionary<string, MovieMapPropertyAttribute> propAtts = new Dictionary<string, MovieMapPropertyAttribute>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                MovieMapPropertyAttribute[] mma = (MovieMapPropertyAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MovieMapPropertyAttribute), false);

                // Attribute found
                if (mma.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Get attribute
                    MovieMapPropertyAttribute mmp = mma[0];

                    // Get value
                    var value = input.GetType().GetProperty(mmp.PropertyName).GetValue(input, null);

                    // Is property a dateTime
                    if (typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                    {
                        // Set value to object
                        obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(value), null);
                    }
                    else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                    {

                    }
                    else if (typeof(Boolean).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                    {
                        // Set value to object
                        obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, Convert.ToBoolean(value), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Set value to object
                        obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, value, null);
                    }
                }                        
            }

        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Wrong object");

        return obj;
    }       
}
```

so atm i got it working that things like int, string, booleans & DateTime are getting mapped to my object.

But as you can see i have a IEnumerable in my TvShow class. This is a collection of Genre for this TvShow.

I'm a bit stuck with how to make 2 IEnumerables map with each other.
if I do it like a string i get this error:

```
a object of type System.Collections.Generic.List can not be converted to the     type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
```

Maybe someone can put me in the right direction in how to handle this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list which is an `IEnumerable`, add the items to it and then assign it to the property.

If you need to convert the objects from `TmdbGenre` to `Genre` you can call `Map` recursively, but you may need a version of `Map` that accepts a type parameter.

```
public object Map(Type type, object input);

var result = value.Select(x => Map(prop.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0], x));
prop.SetValue(obj, result);
```

Comment: that's not going to work I think, because i have to map the objects in the ienumerable first? they have to be mapped from TmdbGenre to Genre..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a lot of trying i've figured it out.

Here's my solution:

```
 public T Map<T>(object input) where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();

        MovieMapAttribute[] classAttributes = (MovieMapAttribute[])obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MovieMapAttribute), false);

        if (classAttributes != null && classAttributes[0].ClassName.Equals(input.GetType().Name))
        {
            Dictionary<string, MovieMapPropertyAttribute> propAtts = new Dictionary<string, MovieMapPropertyAttribute>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                MovieMapPropertyAttribute[] mma = (MovieMapPropertyAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MovieMapPropertyAttribute), false);

                // Attribute found
                if (mma.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Get attribute
                    MovieMapPropertyAttribute mmp = mma[0];

                    if (input.GetType().GetProperty(mmp.PropertyName) != null)
                    {
                        // Get value
                        var value = input.GetType().GetProperty(mmp.PropertyName).GetValue(input, null);

                        // Is property a dateTime
                        if (typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(value), null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string[]))
                        {
                            Type type = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                            var list = (IEnumerable)value;
                            dynamic values = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));

                            foreach (object ob in list)
                            {

                                object tempObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                                tempObj = Map(ob, tempObj);

                                values.Add((dynamic)tempObj);
                            }

                            obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, values, null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(Boolean).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, Convert.ToBoolean(value), null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(value), null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(float).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, float.Parse(value.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat), null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(obj, value, null);
                        }
                    }
                }        
            }

        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Wrong object");

        return obj;
    }       

    private object Map(object input, object output)
    {
        MovieMapAttribute[] classAttributes = (MovieMapAttribute[])output.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MovieMapAttribute), false);

        if (classAttributes != null && classAttributes[0].ClassName.Equals(input.GetType().Name))
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in output.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                MovieMapPropertyAttribute[] mma = (MovieMapPropertyAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MovieMapPropertyAttribute), false);

                // Attribute found
                if (mma.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Get attribute
                    MovieMapPropertyAttribute mmp = mma[0];

                    if (input.GetType().GetProperty(mmp.PropertyName) != null)
                    {

                        var value = input.GetType().GetProperty(mmp.PropertyName).GetValue(input, null);

                        // Is property a dateTime
                        if (typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            output.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(output, Convert.ToDateTime(value), null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string[]))
                        {
                            Type type = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                            var list = (IEnumerable)value;
                            dynamic values = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));

                            foreach (object ob in list)
                            {

                                object tempObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                                tempObj = Map(ob, tempObj);

                                values.Add((dynamic)tempObj);
                            }

                            output.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(output, values, null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(Boolean).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            output.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(output, Convert.ToBoolean(value), null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            output.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(output, Convert.ToInt32(value), null);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(float).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            output.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(output, float.Parse(value.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat), null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Set value to object
                            output.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(output, value, null);
                        }
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Wrong object");

        return output;
    }
```

It works fine, it maps ienumerables in ienumerables etc..

Thank you Ned for pointing me in the right direction, will put u up as a good answer!